# Wireshark: modify existing packet-ospf dissector

Tags: wireshark

I need to modify an existing epan/dissector/packet-ospf.c and add in additional customized decode for a proprietary field. I have the developer environment setup and a base wireshark build done.

Now, can I just copy the packet-ospf.c file from my C:/Development/wireshark/epan/dissectors/packet-ospf.c,
Edit packet-ospf.c and add my modification
Build using "msbuild /m /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo Wireshark.sln" and be able to compile my newly added code?

Thanks
San

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as indicated in the ["Win32/64: Step-by-Step Guide"](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html), once your Wireshark development environment is setup and you've generated the build files, that should be all you need to do.